# How to remove recurrent element from a text file

Tags: c#

I have a text file from which I need to remove a recurrent element. It always starts with prefix *:62M:* and ends with suffix *:86:*. The removed text should contain the prefix and everything coming after the prefix until the suffix, but without it.

So the body before the processing looks like below:

```cs
74FCHGNONREF
:62M:C200918PLN81,67
-}
{1:F01068070965    }{2:0940068070965     N}{4:
:20:200918/10901694
:25:PL8710
:28C:20181/2
:60M:C200918PLN12285581,67
:61:200918CN2024,00FCHGNONREF
:86:BICC?00UZNANIE VAT (SP)?20/VAT
```

and it should look like this:

```cs
74FCHGNONREF
:86:BICC?00UZNANIE VAT (SP)?20/VAT
```

The deleted part may occur many times and its content can vary. Only the prefix and finishing suffix are fixed.

How can I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop over the file with a `foreach` loop pulling from `File.ReadLines(path)`. If the line `StartsWith(":62M:")` toggle a boolean `ignoring` to be `true`. If the line `StartsWith(":86:")` toggle a boolean `ignoring` to be `false`. After you've made these two string assessments, check the state of the `ignoring` variable to know what to do: If you're `ignoring` then don't output the line, otherwise do output the line (collect it into a list, write it to an output etc)

```
bool ignoring = false;
foreach(var line in File.ReadLines(...)){

  if(line.StartsWith(...))
    ignoring = true;
  else if(line.StartsWith(...))
    ignoring = false;

  if(ignoring)
    continue;

  //do whatever with the line here
}
```